# Add item in account menu

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-account

I have an application that has account in accounts and sync. I have option for synchronizing calendar and contacts. In the account there is menu in the upper right corner (standard like on all accounts). You can see what menu I'm talking about on the picture below:

[image]

What I want to do is the following:

**How can I add item in this menu?** Something like **settings** or so.

**Or is there some other way how can I edit settings for this account?**

**I don't wan't to do this through starting the application and then going to settings, I want to do it from here.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through the usage of a `SyncAdapter` with combination of a `Service`.

Here is [a good tutorial (based on Google I/O)](http://naked-code.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/revenge-of-syncadapter-synchronizing.html) to help you get started and working. Also the video shown provides good explanation of a sync adapter.

[This](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/) is another good one.

Comment: I already have a sync adapter and everything is set and it's working fine, I only need to implement some settings.

Comment: I found it on the second link in your answer. It's the `account_preferences.xml` what I was talking about. I just didn't know how to explain it :) Thanks